# Need to sort and print images from a folder

Tags: php, sorting, web

I've a problem I'm trying to create a website where you can upload a pic and after the upload you see the pic that the previous user uploaded.
The images are stored in a folder in my domain but I don't know how to sort them by date, actually I use this code but it didn't go very well

```
<?php
$search_dir = "uploads/".$row['Reference_No'];
$images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
sort($images);
//display first image
if (count($images) > 0) { // at least one image exists
    $img = $images[0];// first image
    echo "<img src='../../$img'  border='0' /> ";
} else {
    shuffle($images);
    echo "<img src='../../$images'  border='0' /> ";        
}
```

Comment: How do you name the files? Is that something you can sort on?

Comment: the files have their original names, I'm using shuffle because if there is any problem with the sorting it print a random image, but ik that shuffle don't sort

Comment: How do you shuffle an array with less than 1 element in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the .jpg's from the target directory, store the last modified timestamp and filename, sort by timestamp then filename (with path removed), sort, then loop again to output the array.

```
$array=[];
foreach(glob("uploads/{$row['Reference_No']}/*.jpg") as $filename){
    // store modified timestamp and path-free filename
    $array[]=[filemtime($filename),substr($filename,strrpos($filename,'/')+1)];
}
sort($array);  // sort on modified timestamp, then on filename to break any ties
foreach($array as $a){
    echo $a[1],'<br>';  // display the filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything to test this on but in theory it should work.

```
$search_dir = "uploads/".$row['Reference_No'];
$images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");

$time = array();
Foreach($images as $file){
    $time[] = filemtime($file);
}

array_multisort($time, $images);

Echo $images[0]; // first image
Echo end($images); // last image
```

Filemtime will get last modified time. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php
Multisort will sort the two arrays with $time as the leading array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: thanks that helped me a lot anyway i have another problem it all works great but only if i change manually  $img = $images[1,2,3,4..]; so i tried using this but $k is stucked on 1

            if (count($images) > 1) { 
            $img = $images[$k];
            echo "<img src='../../$img'  border='0' /> ";
            $k++;
             }

Comment: What do you mean? What is $k? I don't understand what you mean with this comment.

Comment: I see your edit now. Of course $k will be stuck if you don't loop. A if() is not a loop

Comment: yeah I'm trying but i only get infinite loop or $k stucked anyway thank you so much for the help

Comment: Well I don't understand. You say in question you want to show the previous picture. Meaning 1 (one)? Now you talk about an infinitive loop. Posting one image does not need a loop or anything infinitive.

Comment: i got into infinite loop because the script shows all the previous image posted then it starts again but yes it have to show only the previous image

Comment: But how can the code loop if there is no loop?! There must be something you are hiding. A code does not loop by itself.

Comment: See my added code to the answer above.

Comment: the code loop when i try to add a loop to increment the counter that's why it loop

Comment: i tried your code but it only print the first or the last image the scheme I'm trying to get is this: https://textsave.de/text/ONeRQD4chudAzX26

Comment: It's impossible to help you. I give up. I would rather watch paint dry, talk to a brick wall or watch soccer on TV. If I could downvote you more than once I would. I really have tried my best but you keep your code secret. Say you need to print one image but still talk about looping. Say you have an infinitive loop but don't tell me what it looks like. I'm feed up with this. Enough is enough!